# Having trouble converting numbers to word form in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert numbers between 1 and 99 into word form, with numbers above twenty printed as "twenty-one", "twenty-two" and so on. Not sure what I'm missing in my code.

```
zero2nineteen = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten',
                 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 
                 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
zero2ninety = ['zero', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'fourty',
               'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

def number(Number):
    if (Number >= 1) or (Number <= 19):
        return (zero2nineteen[Number])
    elif (Number >= 20) or (Number <= 99):
        return (zero2ninety[Number])
    else:
        print("Done")

def main():
    Number = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 99: "))
    number(Number)

main()
```

Comment: Perhaps provide what output the code is currently giving?

Comment: I either get nothing or this - Please enter a number between 0 and 99: 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/donav/Desktop/Program3.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/donav/Desktop/Program3.py", line 15, in main
    number(Number)
  File "C:/Users/donav/Desktop/Program3.py", line 7, in number
    return (zero2nineteen[Number])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Comment: @DonavonDavis Please add the output that you got in the question, and not as a a comment.

Comment: @DonavonDavis The list index is out of range due to a logical error in your `or` statement. I've posted an answer providing more details.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to avoid using capitalized words for variable names - they are mostly used in `class` definitions. Aside from that, your logic for the conversion is incorrect. Your `number()` method would be modified like such in order to produce the correct results:

```
def number(n):
    # 1. Rename variable
    # 2. Change "or" to "and"

    # If the number is between 0 and 19 (inclusive), refer directly to zero2nineteen list
    if (n >= 0) and (n <= 19):
        return (zero2nineteen[n])

    # If the number is between 20 and 99 (inclusive):
    elif (n >= 20) and (n <= 99):

        # First check if the number is a multiple of ten
        if not n % 10:

            # If it is, refer directly to the zero2ninety list
            return (zero2ninety[n // 10])

        # Else, use the zero2ninety list in conjunction with zero2nineteen
        return (zero2ninety[n // 10] + "-" + zero2nineteen[n % 10])

    # If the number is not between 0 and 99 inclusive, exit
    else:
        print("Done")
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
p.number_to_words(99)
ninety-nine

Comment: I cant import anything

Comment: Although this might have not fitted OP's needs, please at least format your answer correctly with the built-in code formatting tools.

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. You should also add some explanation on what this does and why it helps.